# Sanitize text for Mechanical Turk?

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

Is there a pre-existing function to sanitize a data.frame's character columns for Mechanical Turk?  Here's an example of a line that it's getting hung up on:

```
x <- "Duke\U3e32393cs B or C, no concomittant malignancy, ulcerative colitis, Crohn\U3e32393cs disease, renal, heart or liver failure"
```

I assume those are unicode characters, but MT is not letting me proceed with them in there.  I can obviously regex these out pretty easily, but I use MT a decent bit and was hoping for a more generic solution to remove all non-ascii characters.

**Edit**

I can remove the encoding as follows:

```
> iconv(x,from="UTF-8",to="latin1",sub=".")
[1] "Duke......s B or C, no concomittant malignancy, ulcerative colitis, Crohn......s disease, renal, heart or liver failure"
```

But that still leaves me lacking a more generic solution for vectors that use non-utf8 encodings for *any* element.

```
> dput(vec)
c("Colorectal cancer patients Duke\U3e32393cs B or C, no concomittant malignancy, ulcerative colitis, Crohn\U3e32393cs disease, renal, heart or liver failure", 
"Patients with Parkinson\U3e32393cs Disease not already on levodopa", 
"hi")
```

Note that regular text is encoding "unknown", which has no conversion to "latin1", so simple solutions that use iconv fail.  I have one attempt at a more nuanced solution below, but I'm not very happy with it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to offer dput() on a test object? Attributes would then be attached.

Comment: @Dwin That is the output of `dput()`.  And I copy/pasted it back into R to check that the UTF-8 encoding would be preserved.

Comment: Which part of `iconv(x, "UTF-8", "ASCII", ".")` would you like to be more generic? Do you mean you'd like  something that will detect the current encoding, in case it's something other than UTF-8 or ASCII?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Exactly.  See below.

Answer (score 4):

Going to take a stab at answering my own question and hopefully someone has a better way because I'm not convinced this will handle all funky text:

```
sanitize.text <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x))
  sanitize.each.element <- function(elem) {
    ifelse(
      Encoding(elem)=="unknown",
      elem,
      iconv(elem,from=as.character(Encoding(elem)),to="latin1",sub="")
    )
  }
  x <- sapply(x, sanitize.each.element)
  names(x) <- NULL
  x
}

> sanitize.text(vec)
[1] "Colorectal cancer patients Dukes B or C, no concomittant malignancy, ulcerative colitis, Crohns disease, renal, heart or liver failure"
[2] "Patients with Parkinsons Disease not already on levodopa"                                                                              
[3] "hi"
```

---

And a function to handle MT's other import quirks:

```
library(taRifx)
write.sanitized.csv <- function( x, file="", ... ) {
  sanitize.text <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.character(x))
    sanitize.each.element <- function(elem) {
      ifelse(
        Encoding(elem)=="unknown",
        elem,
        iconv(elem,from=as.character(Encoding(elem)),to="latin1",sub="")
      )
    }
    x <- sapply(x, sanitize.each.element)
    names(x) <- NULL
    x
  }
  x <- japply( df=x, sel=sapply(x,is.character), FUN=sanitize.text)
  colnames(x) <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_", colnames(x) )
  write.csv( x, file, row.names=FALSE, ... )
}
```

**Edit**

For lack of a better place to put this code, you can figure out which element of the character vector is causing problems that even the function above won't fix with something like:

```
#' Function to locate a non-ASCII character
#' @param txt A character vector
#' @return A logical of length length(txt) 
locateBadString <- function(txt) {
  vapply(txt, function(x) {
    class( try( substr( x, 1, nchar(x) ) ) )!="try-error"
  }, TRUE )
}
```

**Edit2**

I *think* that this should work:

```
iconv(x, to = "latin1", sub="")
```

Thanks to @Masoud in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250920/636656