# Replace expression '&auml;' by 'ae' in R

Tags: r, csv, replace

i have imported a .csv with several rows&columns(alphanumeric values) in RSTUDIO which contains expressions like `&auml;` for the german  'ä'.

Next i want to do some Text mining but first i have to replace all the `&auml;` expressions with 'ae'. (or likewise `&uuml;` with 'ue')

I looked up for commands like gsub, regmatches or something like that...but i don't get it :-(
I just want to find a way to search all `&uuml;` expressions and replace them with "ä" or "ae"...

Can anybody help me ?  Thanks

Comment: What did you try when you looked up `gsub` and related functions?

Comment: Why not using a [HTML decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/decode.aspx) first?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345212/sanitize-text-for-mechanical-turk/11346767#11346767 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369668/how-to-match-all-internationalized-text

Comment: I have to admit i am really a greenhorn in R . @ Ananda Matho: I just searched for possible solutions to my Problem.... @krlmlr and Ari B. Friedman...i will look up your recommendations, thank you !  Is there not just a easy way to say to R  "just search "that" in "this" csv, and replace it with "that"?! :-)

Comment: @Laudl007: Try `gsub('a', 'b', c('a', 'b', 'c'))`, and, if required, an [R tutorial](http://www.statmethods.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example of how to use gsub which should get you started.

We start by creating a short character vector.

```
characters <- c("a small phrase", "a longer phrase", "a", "word")
```

Observe how each of these gsub commands changes the vector.

```
gsub("a", "", characters)
gsub("a ", "", characters)
gsub("phrase", "something", characters)
```

The first argument specifies what you are looking for the second specifies what you are replacing it with and the third says what object you apply it to.

We can then change the characters object by assigning the output of gsub to it.

```
characters <- gsub("phrase", "something", characters)
```

Now when we run `characters` we get:

```
[1] "a small something"  "a longer something" "a"                  "word"
```

Also, unless you really need the umlauted characters you'll be better off using the latin equivalent (ae) as not all R functions have great unicode support.

Comment: Thanks for that example, i think i get it! ...but this doesn´t work for my Dataframe with 8 obs. of 2 variables.  When i try ´revs2  =gsub('&auml;','ae',revs2)´ i get back a vector of course. I want to search and replace in my Dataframe.

Comment: The easiest way is to do it a column at a time. revs2$varname1 <- gsub('&auml;','ae',revs2$varname1)