# Error in simple_triplet_matrix -- unable to use RWeka to count Phrases

Tags: r, tm

Using TM, I'm comparing a DocumentTermMatrix against a dictionary list to count totals:

```
totals <- inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(x, list(dictionary = d)))
```

This works great for single words, but I want to include double words and can't figure out how to do this.

I tried RWeka:

```
TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, 
                                               Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(v.corpus, 
                          control = list(tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))
```

BUt get the following error message:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
  'i, j, v' different lengths
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In parallel::mclapply(x, termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
3: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion.
```

Can you help with the Error message?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried some of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18504559/1036500)?

Comment: I voted to close as there's no [Minimal Working Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663160/1069256)

> Seems there are problems using **RWeka** with **parallel** package. I
>   found workaround solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663160/1069256)
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663160/1069256):
>   http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RWeka-and-multicore-package-td4678473.html#a4678948
>
> > The most important point is not loading the RWeka package and use the namespace in a encapsulated  function.
>
> So your tokenizer should look like
>
> ```
> BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}
> ```